# Removing nodes in XML with XPath and PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have an `XML`:

```
<root>
   <level name="main">
      <level name="sub_1">
         <content id="abc123" />
      </level>
   </level>
</root>
```

I would like to search for the node with `id` that is `abc123` and delete the `<content>` and its parent `<level>`

So the end result would be:

```
<root>
  <level name="main">
  </level> 
</root>
```

I have tried this in PHP without result, what am I doing wrong?

```
 $doc = new DOMDocument;
 $doc->loadxml($xml_from_file); 
 $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
 $node_list = $xpath->query("content[@id='abc123']/parent::*"); 
 $node = $node_list->item(0); 
 $doc->removeChild($node);
```

Comment: `DOMDocument::loadXML` takes XML. Use `DOMDocument::load` for filename.

Comment: Thanks. I am actually loading it from a string within `loadXML`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are two issues with your source.

The expression does only match child nodes. You need to start it with `//` to match any node: `//content[@id='abc123']/parent::*`.

The found node is not a child of the document so, you need to remove it from its own parent: `$node->parentNode->removeChild($node);`.

I suggest using a `foreach` to avoid problems if the node doesn't exists.

```
$document = new DOMDocument;
$document->loadxml($xmlString); 
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate("//content[@id='abc123']/parent::*") as $node) {
  $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

echo $document->saveXml();
```

Edit: PHP 8 got several new DOM standard methods. One of them is `remove()`:

```
$document = new DOMDocument;
$document->loadxml($xmlString); 
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate("//content[@id='abc123']/parent::*") as $node) {
  // new shortcut method
  $node->remove();
}

echo $document->saveXml();
```

Comment: How to convert this into a well-formed XML?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$xml_from_file = '<root>
   <level name="main">
      <level name="sub_1">
         <content id="abc123" />
      </level>
   </level>
</root>';

 $doc = new DOMDocument;
 $doc->loadxml($xml_from_file); 
 $xpath_selector = new DOMXPath($doc);
//Here you forget at the begin the //
 $node_list = $xpath_selector->query("//content[@id='abc123']/parent::*"); 
//here you get the reference to the parent of content
 $node = $node_list->item(0); 
//but for remove the child you need to go to the parent node
 $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
 echo $doc->saveXML();

?>
```

Output:

```
<root>
  <level name="main">
  </level> 
</root>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is kind of a hack but I got it to work with your example. One problem is likely with your `xpath` query--note the `//` at the beginning.

```
$xml_string = '<root>
    <level name="main">
        <level name="sub_1">
            <content id="abc123" />
        </level>
    </level>
</root>';

// using SimpleXMLElement instead of DOMDocument
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_string);

// standardize the string version of the xml so str_replace works
$xml_string = $xml->asXML();

// search for the target; note the // at the beginning of the query
$target = $xml->xpath("//content[@id='abc123']/parent::*");

// use simple string replacement to remove the node
echo str_replace($target[0]->asXML(), '', $xml_string);
```

Not very elegant, but it seemed to take care of your problem.

Comment: When dealing with XML it is generally a bad idea to try to manipulate it with string functions, as the structure is intricate and subtle (think of entities, cdata sections, comments, dtd). It is almost always better to use XML classes, like available for DOM, XPath, XQuery or XSLT.